# Automating scaleup of Streaming units - Stream analytics job

Tags: azure-stream-analytics, azure-automation

We would like to automate scale up of streaming units for certain stream analytics job if the 'SU utilization' is high. Is it possible to achieve this using PowerShell? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, as Pete M said, we could call [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/streamanalytics/stream-analytics-transformation) to create or update a transformation within a job.

[image]

Besides, Azure Stream Analytics Cmdlets `New-AzureRmStreamAnalyticsTransformation` could be used to update a transformation within a job.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Depends on what you mean by "automate". You can update a transformation via the API from a scheduled job, including streaming unit allocation. I'm not sure if you can do this via the PS object model but you can always make a rest call: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/streamanalytics/stream-analytics-transformation

If you mean you want to use powershell to create and configure a job to automatically scale on its own, unfortunately today that isn't possible regardless of how you create the job. ASA doesn't support elastic scaling. You have to do it "manually", either by hand or some manner of scheduled webjob or similar.

Comment: Thank you Pete. Probably I can use 'invoke-webrequest' from PS

Answer (score 0):

It is three years later now, but I think you can use App Insights to automatically create an alert rule based on percent utilization. Is it an absolute MUST that you use powershell? If so, there is an Azure Automation Script on Github:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-stream-analytics/blob/master/Autoscale/StepScaleUp.ps1